# For Loop Incremented by 3 when char is read

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, try-catch

Could anyone tell me why is the for loop bellow incremented by 3 each time I read a char ?

```
         public class Test {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                 char ch1=' ';
                 for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
                     try { ch1 = (char) System.in.read(); 
                     } catch(Exception e) {}
                     System.out.println(i);
                 }
              }
         }
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? This doesn't display the behavior you described: http://ideone.com/lB4eSs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal only lets you read whole lines at a time. When you press enter it sends the carriage-return line-feed sequence (2 characters) marking the end of the line. You can filter these out by wrapping it in a `do` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
    do {
        try {
            ch1 = (char)System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    } while (ch1 == '\n' || ch1 == '\r');
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Note that if you create a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) from `System.in`, it has methods for getting whole-line input and other things that make it much easier to use than processing individual bytes.